# SQL syntax error Maria DB server Mysqli_query

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have this SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (ID, Order_ID, Status, FName, LName, Email, 
Phone)VALUES ($UID, $orderID, 'Pending', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', 
'$phone');
INSERT INTO orders_inventory (Order_invID, Item_ID, Order_ID, Quantity) 
VALUES 
(NULL, $item_ID, $orderID, 1);";
```

This is how I connect it:

```
if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
   echo "three";
}
```

I did an echo on the `$sql` and this is what I got:

```
INSERT INTO orders (ID, Order_ID, Status, FName, LName, Email, Phone) 
VALUES (92, 625015841, 'Pending', '1', '1', '1@1', '1'); 
INSERT INTO orders_inventory (Order_invID, Item_ID, Order_ID, Quantity) 
VALUES (NULL, 1, 625015841, 1);
```

The SQL works when I paste it into the database manually, but the database crashes when I use the website PHP. The `$DB` is to connect to the database and it works because I tested it, and I have also been using it throughout the whole website.

I then did an error check using `mysqli_error(db)` and I get this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO orders_inventory (Order_invID, Item_ID, Order_ID, Quantity) VALUES (' at line 2"

Help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very stuck and don't know how to get around this or fix this problem

Comment: sorry the database doesnt crash when i use the website php, the php code just doesnt reach the echo "three"

Comment: try and execute the two statements one by one

Comment: Try removing the semicolon at the end. The semicolon is not part of SQL and some database drivers don't like it.

Comment: Wait... those are TWO statements! Run them separately.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked, but im still confused in why the sql worked when copied it and pasted it in manually but it didnt work when php entered it?

Comment: Command line and GUI tools usually support multi-statements, whille the PHP API does not (per default).

Comment: Thank you guys for that help, that helps alot!

Comment: @mario the PHP mysqli API does support multi-statements through [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @Nick Hence the "per default". Albeit that's really just a peculiarity of mysqli. -- PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS is active usually.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to run two queries at once, which `mysqli_query` will not do. However you can use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead:

```
if(mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql)){
    echo "three";
}
```